# Unpacking a .deb file containing a MIPS binary

Tags: dpkg, deb

I'm trying to install openssh server on a router and need a MIPS compiled binary. I've downloaded the one from [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mips/openssh-server/download) but encounter an error upon extraction:

```
$ sudo dpkg --unpack openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb 
dpkg: error processing openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb (--unpack):
 package architecture (mips) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb
```

**dpkg** is also prompting me for administrative privileges which suggests that it's trying to install the package, not extract it. I cannot extract/install the .deb file on the router as it does not have **dpkg** or any package utility. I can only copy the server as is and issue a number of commands to create the appropriate directories and keys.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
dpkg -x openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb openssh_mips_outdir
```

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg` is the tool to manipulate the database of installed packages. The tool to manipulate a `.deb` file is [`dpkg-deb`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg-deb).

```
dpkg-deb -x openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb openssh-server_mips
```

or

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb | gzip -9 >openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.tgz
```

If you prefer, you can use `dpkg` instead of `dpkg-deb`, since it passes `dpkg-deb` commands through. But make sure you're using the correct options; for example `--unpack` is a command of `dpkg` proper, which means to do one step of package installation (the step where the package content is unpacked into a Debian installation).

Alternatively, if you don't have `dpkg`, you can use [`ar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) and [`tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).

```
ar p openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.deb data.tar.xz >openssh-server_6.0p1-4+deb7u2_mips.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 1):

A deb is just an `ar` archive, so you can open it any archive viewer program.